# form validation with nested models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have this problem.  I need to validate the attributes of two models in the same form in Rails.  One is the parent of the other.

The form is like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @professional do |pro| %>
       <%= pro.inputs :id => "information" do %>
          <%= pro.input :name, label: t("Artistic Name") %>
         <%= pro.semantic_fields_for @user do |user| %>

         <%= user.inputs :id => "register" do %>

            <%= user.input :email, :placeholder=>"email@example.com" %>

           <%= user.input :password, label: t('Password') %>

          <%end%>

       <% end %>

   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

The models I am using are like this:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true
  validates  :email, :password, presence: true

end
```

Professionals:

```
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :user, as: :role, dependent: :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

   validates  :date_birthday, :gender, :height, :name, :description, :Weight, :address, :languages,:services, :category, :phonenumber, :fullname, :hair_color, :age, :orientation, presence: true

end
```

So, what is the problem?

When I clicked in the submit button  the professional attributes are marked but not the users attributes.

Like this:

[image]

The fields marked in red belongs to the professional model but the fields email and password  belongs to the user model aren't marked in red  when it should be because they are empty.

What can i do?  I need the warning message for the user is attributes too

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Do you have the associations set up correctly?

Comment: @RichPeck  I edited the models codes with the association between both models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've achieved what you need before.

We had to use [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) so that the object was a singular piece of data (rather than multiple pieces as is the case by default):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :user
  validates  :email, :password, presence: true
end

#app/models/professional.rb
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :role, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

[This](https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations#creating-an-object-and-its-children-via-accepts_nested_attributes_for-in-a-has_many-association) will help.

You also need to make sure you're passing these objects correctly (I see so many people not doing this).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Professional to validate the associated User:

```
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
    ... 
    validates_associated :user
```